# How can I get selected value from mvc dropdown list as action link id in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have a `Html.DropdownList()` which I have binded data with a viewbag. It works properly. Now what I want is when user select and item from it and after click the action link the selected Item value should set as action link id using jquery or, send the selected item value to a specific controller as a parameter directly. How can I do that?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 style="color: #2f6207">dfdfDestination</h2>
    @Html.DropDownList("Destin",new SelectList(ViewBag.Destination, "regCde", "Destination","--pickone--"))
</div>
<div class="mylink">
    @Html.ActionLink("SEARCH NOW", "MscHome", new {@id = "ssd"})
</div>
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you using jquery, you can make ajax call:

```
$('#Destin').on('change', function (){ //on change drop down selected value
   $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("YourMethod","YourController")',
     cache: false,
     type: "POST", //Or GET
     dataType: "json",
     data: $(this).val(), //here you set your dropdown selected value
     success: function(data){
       $("#results").append(data); //append your data from controller
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: You are really rockstar :D